# Pandas: Get substring between start and end of the characters

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, substring

I am attempting to get substring between start and end of different characters. I tried several different regex notations, I am coming close to the output I need, but it is not fully correct. What can I do to fix this?

Data csv

```
ID,TEST
abc,1#London4#Harry Potter#5Rowling##
cde,6#Harry Potter1#England#5Rowling
efg,4#Harry Potter#5Rowling##1#USA
ghi,
jkm,4#Harry Potter5#Rowling
xyz,4#Harry Potter1#China#5Rowling
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
print(df)
```

Try:

```
df['TEST'].astype(str).str.extract('(1#.*(?=#))')
```

Got output from above code: It doesn't pick up end line '1#USA'

```
1#London4#Harry Potter#5Rowling#
1#England
NaN
NaN
NaN
1#China
```

Output needed:

```
1#London
1#England
1#USA
NaN
NaN
1#China
```

Comment: How about `df['TEST'].astype(str).str.extract('(1#.*?(?=#|$|\d))')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> df.TEST.str.extract("(1#[a-zA-Z]*)")
           0
0   1#London
1  1#England
2      1#USA
3        NaN
4        NaN
5    1#China
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# capture all characters that are neither `#` nor digits
# following 1#
df['TEST'].str.extract('(1#[^#\d]+)', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
0     1#London
1    1#England
2        1#USA
3          NaN
4          NaN
5      1#China
Name: TEST, dtype: object
```